# jQuery Resizable textarea is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is jquery code.

```
$( '#textarea_introduce' ).resizable( {
    helper : 'ui-state-highlight',
    handles : 'se'
} );
```

and markup is

```
<div id="box_formIntroduce">
  <label for="textarea_introduce" id="label_introduce">
    <fmt:message bundle="${ resourceMessage }" key="label_introduce" />
  </label>
  <textarea name="introduce" id="textarea_introduce" cols="20" rows="5">
    ${ resource.beforeValueMap.introduce }
  </c:if>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

It is not working.
I cannot found any fault...
What is wrong with that?

Test environment: Chrome

Comment: What do you mean by "not completely working"?

Comment: check console for the errors if any i will also advise you to test in in mozilla firefox and see firebug error console and post those errors here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I used some of your code and the  following works in chrome and ie8

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
type="text/css" media="all"> 

</head>
<body>
<div id="box_formIntroduce">   
<label for="textarea_introduce" id="label_introduce">
</label>   
<textarea name="introduce" id="textarea_introduce" cols="20" rows="5"> 
</textarea> 
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#textarea_introduce").resizable();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, I'd put the jQuery code initialising the `.resizable()` in the familiar document loaded code, just to make sure there is a text-area available for resizing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#textarea_introduce' ).resizable( {
        helper : 'ui-state-highlight',
        handles : 'se'
    } );
});
```

Comment: You're using Chrome, right? Hit F12, click on `console`, then refresh your page...what errors show up there?

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't attach a CSS file.

Comment: Do they have a facepalm emoticon for StackOverflow.com? (>__<)